# Command substitution as a variable in one-liner

Tags: string, bash, zsh, pbs, command-substitution

I get the following error:

```
> echo "${$(qstat -a | grep kig):0:7}"
-bash: ${$(qstat -a | grep kig):0:7}: bad substitution
```

I'm trying to take the number before`.` of

```
> qstat -a | grep kig
1192530.perceus-     kigumen     lr_regul pbs.sh            27198     2     16    --  24:00:00 R 00:32:23
```

and use it as an argument to `qdel` in openPBS so that I can delete all process that I started with my login `kigumen`

so ideally, this should work:

```
qdel ${$(qstat -a | grep kig):0:7}
```

so far, only this works:

```
str=$(qstat -a | grep kig); qdel "${str:0:7}"
```

but I want a clean one-liner without a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell substring construct you're using (`:0:7`) only works on variables, not command substitution. If you want to do this in a single operation, you'll need to trim the string as part of the pipeline, something like one of these:

```
echo "$(qstat -a | grep kig | sed 's/[.].*//')"
echo "$(qstat -a | awk -F. '/kig/ {print $1}')"
echo "$(qstat -a | awk '/kig/ {print substr($0, 1, 7)}')"
```

(Note that the first two print everything before the first ".", while the last prints the first 7 characters.) I don't know that any of them are particularly cleaner, but they do it without a temp variable...

Comment: Not without storing it in a variable first. Shell substitutions aren't nestable like true string expressions, so you basically only get one "operation" per substitution. e.g. you can do a command substitution OR a substring of a variable OR a variable with a prefix pattern removed OR a variable with a suffix pattern removed... but only one of them at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
qstat -u palle | cut -f 1 -d "." | xargs qdel
```

Kills all my jobs... normally I grep out the jobname(s) before cut'ing...

So I use a small script "idlist":

```
qstat -u palle | grep -E "*.in" | grep -E "$1" | cut -f 1 -d "." | xargs
```

To see all my "map_..." jobs:

```
idlist "map_*"
```

For killing all my "map_...." jobs:

```
idlist "map_*" | xargs qdel
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another ways :

```
    foreach   m1 in $(qstat -a );do
           if [[ $m1 =~ kig ]];then
               m2=${m1%.kig}
               echo "kig found $m2 "
               break
           fi
    done
```